# Android: How to get contacts pictures from Call log query

Tags: android

I have created an activity that displays the phone call log (just like the native call log). Now i want to display the contact picture next to each entry. To get the last week call log i have used the following query:

```
String[] projection = new String[]
        { Calls.DATE, Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DURATION, Calls.CACHED_NAME, Calls.TYPE };

    Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, Calls.DATE + ">?", new String[]
        { String.valueOf(weekAgo.getTime()) }, Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Cant find a good way to get each entry picture. With this query I get the log data without the indication for the contact id or photo id.

Any way to get the contact photo as a Bitmap from the data I do have (like the phone number) ? I want the picture as shown on the native android call log (even if it's a synced one...)

I am using SDK 8. (ContactsContract)

Answer (score 1):

The `CallLog` content provider does not record much information about the contact, so there are no relational ties between the `CallLog` and the contacts. For example, what if the user deletes the contact? That would cause some sort of foreign key violation in the `CallLog`, if the `CallLog` were holding some sort of hard identifier pointing back to a contact.

You are welcome to use `CACHED_NAME`, `CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL`, and `CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE` to try to find a contact associated with a given call, but you need to handle the case where you cannot find such a contact, either because the contact does not exist or the contact data changed (e.g., new phone number).

Comment: I have no problem if i can't find the contact. In a case where i cant find the contact i will display a default picture. Any example on how can i use the cached phone number to get the profile default picture?